# Storing a Billing Address Best Practice in Orders Table

Tags: database-design, best-practices

Can someone help me understand this user's answer for a [CustomerLocation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61342/storing-a-shipping-address-best-practice/80611#80611) table. I really want a good method for storing addresses in the orders table.

What I'm looking for is how I can set up my addresses so when I edit
them, the order is not effected by the fact that a customer updates
his address or relocates.

As it stands my schema looks similar to:

```
 Person           |EntityID|
 EntityAddress    |EntityID|AddressID|
 Address          |AddressID|AddressType|AddressLine1|AddressLine2|
 Order            |OrderID|BillingAddressID|
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Conceptually speaking, although in your business environment *Order* and *Address* are ideas that are closely associated, they are in effect two separate entity types, each with its own set of applicable properties (or attributes) and constraints.

Therefore, as previously stated in comments, I agree with [@Erik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/72091/erik), and you should organize the logical layout of your database declaring among other elements:

- one discrete table to keep *Address* pieces of information;
- one table to retain *Customer*-specific details;
- one table to enclose *Order* data points; and
- one table to contain facts about the associations between *Customer(s)* and *Address(es)*;

as I will exemplify below.

## Expository IDEF1X diagram

A picture is worth a thousand words, so I created the IDEF1X diagram shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrL0k.png) to illustrate some of the possibilities opened by my suggestion:

[image: Figure 1 - Customers, Orders and Addresses Expository IDEF1X Diagram]

***Customer*, *Address* and their associations**

As demonstrated, I portrayed an association with a many-to-many (M:N) cardinality ratio between the entity types *Customer*<sup>**a**</sup> and *Address*; this approach would provide future flexibility because, as you know, a *Customer* can keep multiple *Addresses* over time, or even simultaneously, and the same *Address* can be shared by multiple *Customers*.

A particular *Address* can be used in several ways by one-to-many (1:M) *Customers*; e.g., it can be defined as *Physical*, and/or it can be set for *Shipping*, and/or for *Billing*. Perhaps, the same *Address* instance can serve each of the aforementioned purposes at the same time, or it may be covering two uses while a different *Address* occurrence covers the remaining one.

---

<sup><sup>**a**</sup> In some business environments, a *Customer* can be either a *Person* or an *Organization* (situation that would imply a slightly distinct arrangement, as detailed [in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179712/63644) about a supertype-subtype structure) but with the objective of providing a simplified example, I decided not to include that possibility here. In case you need to cover that situation in your database, the previously linked post shows the method to solve said requirement.</sup>

---

***Order*, *Address*, *CustomerAddress* and *Address Roles***

Commonly, an *Order* requires only two kinds of *Addresses*, one for *Shipping* and one for *Billing* . In this way, the same *Address* instance could fill both *Roles* for an individual *Order*, but each *Role* is pictured by the respective property, i.e., *ShippingAddressId* or *BillingAddressId*.

*Order* is connected with *Address* via the *CustomerAddress* associative entity type with the aid of two multi-property FOREIGN KEYs, i.e.,

- (*CustomerNumber*, *ShippingAddressId*), and (*CustomerNumber*, *BillingAddressId*),

both pointing to the *CustomerAddress* multi-property PRIMARY KEY shown as

- (*CustomerNumber*, *AddressId*)

… which helps to represent a business rule that stipulates that (a) an *Order* instance must be linked exclusively with (b) *Address* occurrences previously associated with the specific *Customer* who made that *Order*, and never with (c) a random non-*Customer*-related *Address*.

***History* for (1) *Address* and for (2) the *CustomerAddress* association**

If you want to supply the possibility of modifying *Address* pieces of information, then you have to keep track of all the data changes. In this manner I depicted *Address* as an “auditable” entity type that maintains its own *AddressHistory*.

Since the nature of a connection between a *Customer* and an *Address* can also suffer one or more modifications, I have as well depicted the possiblity of handling such an association as an “auditable” one by virtue of the *CustomerAddressHistory* entity type.

In this respect, various factors dealt with in [Q & A no. 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107354/storing-created-retired-dates-for-a-large-amount-of-different-entities/107575#107575) and [Q & A no. 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112314/63644), —both about enabling *temporal* capabilities in a database— are really relevant.

## Illustrative SQL-DDL logical layout

Consequently, in terms of the diagram displayed and explained above, I declared the following logical-level arrangement (which you can adapt to meet your needs with exactitude):

```
-- You should determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all your table columns 
-- depending on your business context characteristics.

-- Also, you should make accurate tests to define the 
-- most convenient INDEX strategies based on the exact 
-- data manipulation tendencies of your business domain.

-- As one would expect, you are free to utilize 
-- your preferred (or required) naming conventions. 

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerNumber      INT      NOT NULL,
    SpecificAttribute   CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ParticularAttribute CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    CreatedDateTime     DATETIME NOT NULL,
    -- 
    CONSTRAINT Customer_PK PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Address (
    AddressId           INT      NOT NULL,
    SpecificAttribute   CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ParticularAttribute CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    CreatedDateTime     DATETIME NOT NULL,  
    -- 
    CONSTRAINT Address_PK PRIMARY KEY (AddressId)
);

CREATE TABLE CustomerAddress (
    CustomerNumber  INT      NOT NULL,  
    AddressId       INT      NOT NULL,
    IsPhysical      BIT      NOT NULL,
    IsShipping      BIT      NOT NULL,  
    IsBilling       BIT      NOT NULL,
    IsActive        BIT      NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,  
    -- 
    CONSTRAINT CustomerAddress_PK           PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber, AddressId),
    CONSTRAINT CustomerAddressToCustomer_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber)
        REFERENCES Customer (CustomerNumber),
    CONSTRAINT CustomerAddressToAddress_FK  FOREIGN KEY (AddressId)
        REFERENCES Address  (AddressId)  
);

CREATE TABLE MyOrder (
    CustomerNumber      INT      NOT NULL,  
    OrderNumber         INT      NOT NULL,
    ShippingAddressId   INT      NOT NULL,
    BillingAddressId    INT      NOT NULL,    
    SpecificAttribute   CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ParticularAttribute CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    OrderDate           DATE     NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime     DATETIME NOT NULL,  
    -- 
    CONSTRAINT Order_PK                  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber, OrderNumber),
    CONSTRAINT OrderToCustomer_FK        FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber)
        REFERENCES Customer        (CustomerNumber),
    CONSTRAINT OrderToShippingAddress_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber, ShippingAddressId)
        REFERENCES CustomerAddress (CustomerNumber, AddressId),
    CONSTRAINT OrderToBillingAddress_FK  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber, BillingAddressId)
        REFERENCES CustomerAddress (CustomerNumber, AddressId)          
);

CREATE TABLE AddressHistory (
    AddressId           INT      NOT NULL,
    AuditedDateTime     DATETIME NOT NULL,
    SpecificAttribute   CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ParticularAttribute CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    CreatedDateTime     DATETIME NOT NULL,  
    -- 
    CONSTRAINT AddressHistory_PK          PRIMARY KEY (AddressId, AuditedDateTime),
    CONSTRAINT AddressHistoryToAddress_FK FOREIGN KEY (AddressId)
        REFERENCES Address  (AddressId)    
);

CREATE TABLE CustomerAddressHistory (
    CustomerNumber  INT      NOT NULL,  
    AddressId       INT      NOT NULL,
    AuditedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,    
    IsPhysical      BIT      NOT NULL,
    IsShipping      BIT      NOT NULL,  
    IsBilling       BIT      NOT NULL,
    IsActive        BIT      NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,  
    -- 
    CONSTRAINT CustomerAddressHistory_PK                  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber, AddressId, AuditedDateTime),
    CONSTRAINT CustomerAddressHistoryToCustomerAddress_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber, AddressId)
        REFERENCES CustomerAddress (CustomerNumber, AddressId)
);
```

If you want to have a look, I tested it [in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1553e8260c191e8eb9696d7850ac8ea3) that runs on SQL Server 2017.

**The `History` tables**

The following excerpt from your question is very important:

> What I'm looking for is how I can set up my addresses so when I edit them, the order is not affected by the fact that a customer updates his address or relocates.

The `AddressHistory` and `CustomerAddressHistory` tables aid in ensuring that an *Order* is not affected by *Address* changes, as all the “previous” rows should be retained in the respective `History` table and may be involved in SELECT queries whenever necessary.

The *Interval* encompassed between the values enclosed in `AddressHistory.CreatedDateTime` and `AddressHistory.AuditedDateTime` stands for the entire *Period* during which a certain “past” `Address` row was  deemed “present”, “current” or “effective”. Similar considerations apply to the `CustomerAddressHistory` rows.

In turn, the `CustomerAddress.IsActive` BIT (boolean) column is meant to point out whether a certain `Address` row is “usable” by a `Customer` row or not; e.g., if it is set to ‘false’ it would convey the situation in which a *Customer* is not using that *Address* anymore and hence it cannot be used for new *Orders*.

#### Data manipulation factors

**Modifiying and erasing**

If a *Customer* wants to change one or more pieces of information about a given “current” *Address*, one must ensure that (a) the corresponding `Address` row that was “present” until the modification took place is INSERTed into the `AddressHistory` table, and also that (b) the `Address` row in question is UPDATEd with the new value(s). I suggest that you carry out this process as a single unit of work inside an individual [ACID TRANSACTION](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1).

UPDATE operations on the two `History` tables should be forbidden (trying to “change” history can even have negative legal implications), since each row retained in that “kind” of tables represents a fact that happened in the past, thus it cannot be modified and a row about it should not be altered.

As for DELETEs on these tables, there are very specific cases where they must be enabled in order to comply with, say, confidentiality laws/policies —but that, as usual, depends entirely on the exact requirements of the business environment of significance—.

**Retrieval and physical-level tuning**

The “present”, “current” or “effective” version of an *Address* occurrence must be contained as a row in the `Address` table, but SELECTing the previous “states” of an *Address* FROM the `AddressHistory` (or from `CustomerAddressHistory`) table is easy, and it may be an interesting exercise to enhance your SQL coding skills.

With respect to one of the situations that you mentioned in comments, if you want to retrieve the “second to last version” of an individual `Address` row FROM its `AddressHistory`, you have to take into account the `MAX(AddressHistory.AuditedDateTime)` and the `AddressHistory.AddressId` that matches the particular `Address.AddressId` value at hand.

In this regard —at least when building a *relational* database—, it is quite convenient to first define the corresponding *conceptual* schema (based on the applicable *business rules*) and after that declare its subsequent *logical* DDL arrangement. Once you obtain stable and reliable versions of these fundamental elements (which, of course, can evolve over time), it is time to analyze and determine the best ways to manipulate (via INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and SELECT operations or combinations thereof) the concerning data, taking care of the optimization of the respective physical level processing (by dint of, e.g., index tunning, hardware upgrades, proper software settings, etc.).

#### End-users perception, *views* and application program(s) assistance

Evidently, at the *external* level of abstraction, *Address* information is perceived (by end-users) as being part of an *Order* —and there is nothing wrong with it—, but that does not necessarily mean that the modelers have to design the significant parts of the database in question in correspondance with said perception. On this point, if there is the need to, e.g., print a “full” *Order* (very feasible), you can “reproduce” it on-demand with the help of a few JOIN operators and WHERE clauses (considering the concerning validity period, etc.) maybe fixed in *views* for future consumption, sending the pertinent data set to the related application program(s) that, in turn, can enhance its formatting as necessary.

Of course, the application program(s) will be very helpful too when an *Order* is being effectuated; e.g., a desktop/mobile app window or a web page can:

- display only the *Address(es)* that the involved *Customer* has established as “usable” (via `CustomerAddress.IsActive`);
- list together all the *Addresses* that the *Customer* has enabled for billing service (via `CustomerAddress.IsBilling`); and
- group all the *Addresses* that the *Customer* has defined for shipping service (via `CustomerAddress.IsShipping`);

facilitating in this manner all the involved processes at the GUI (which, naturally, is part of the external level of abstraction of a computerized system).

---

## Alternative

On the other hand, I have seen some systems in which every time that a new *Order* is effectuated the relevant *Address* information has to be entered (sometimes repeatedly), and the *Address(es)* used for past *Orders* are never erased, hence the *Orders* are not affected by *Address* changes.

This course of action can decidedly involve substantial volumes of data duplication, but it is a possibility that —depending on the exact informational requirements of your business domain— could work, so you might like to evaluate its pros and cons as well.

---

## Comment interactions

> Could you explain me the reason we need an `Address` entity? wouldn't be enough just have `CustomerAddress`? – [@Cristiano](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/172976/cristiano), on [Mar 11 at 19:38:05Z](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111101/storing-a-billing-address-best-practice-in-orders-table/111115#comment516362_111115)

In this specific case, the original poster —with a now deleted account— presented a scenario involving an *Address* entity type that holds four discrete properties of interest, i.e., *AddressID*, *AddressType*, *AddressLine1* and *AddressLine2* —as shown in the question itself—, each of which (a) has a particular set of valid values, (b) involves a potential exclusive set of constraints and (c) implies values that have to be manipulated separately. In addition, (d) any given *Address* instance —i.e., the proper *Address* entities— may be associated with *n* occurrences of entities of other types; therefore, (e) *Address* is an entity type in its own right.

There very well may be other situations where, depending on the exact business requirements, a *Customer.Address* should be treated as a single property, in which case its values have to be handled *atomically* at the logical level of abstraction, i.e., you always manipulate every *Address* value as a whole, never perform operations (INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs, SELECTs) on certain value part(s) only. Of course, if required, one should first set up constraints for the corresponding atomic `Customer.Address` column, since these would not be necessary for column “fractions”. One of these situations *could* be the scenario discussed in the prior section that is entitled “Alternative”.

## Suggested reading

You requested (in now removed comments) some pointers about sound database literature; therefore, as for *theoretical* material, I highly advise that you read all the work written by [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm), a *Turing Award* recipient and, of course, the *sole originator* of the [*relational model of data*](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685) (maybe now more relevant than ever). [This list](http://amturing.acm.org/bib/codd_1000892.cfm) includes some of his tremendously influential articles and papers.

Two important works that are not comprised in the aforesaid list are, precisely, his ACM Turing Award Lecture entitled [*Relational Database: A Practical Foundation for Productivity*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=358400), from 1981, and his book denominated [*The Relational Model for Database Management: Version 2*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=77708), which was published in 1990.

On the *conceptual* design front, [*Integrated Definition for Information Modeling*](http://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/) (IDEF1X) is a seriously recommendable technique that was defined as a standard in December 1993 by the U.S. *National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST).

Comment: Sorry, I know the post is older, but why are you referencing (for example: REFERENCES Address  (AddressId)) in MyOrder? Why not CustomerAddress?

Comment: No worries, and nice catch: As a matter of fact, both `MyOrder.ShippingAddressId` and `MyOrder.BillingAddressId` must make a reference to `CustomerAddress.AddressId` (and not to `Address.AddressId`); in this way one ensures that an *Order* can exclusively be associated with the *Address(es)* previously connected with the *Customer* who made that *Order*. The diagram suggests this arrangement, so the DDL will be more accurate. Thanks for requesting that clarification.

Comment: @Shadrix I just edited the post, in case you want to take a look.

Comment: @MDCCL When you said no UPDATE and DELETE on `History` table, should it be same for `Address` table? What if Customer Orders something and then changes only the postcode or city just one field. We should insert the existing address into `History` and then make a new insert into `Address` table, right?

Comment: @MikeRoss UPDATE operations should not be permited on `History` tables because each row retained in that “kind” of tables represents a fact that was “current” from (1) the `CreatedDateTime` datum until (2) the `UpdatedDateTime` data point; one cannot change a fact in the past, so a row about it should not be changed either. As for DELETE operations on `History` tables, there are very specific cases where they should be enabled in order to comply with, say, confidentiality policies, but that depends on the exact requirements of the business environment of significance.

Comment: OTOH, if a *Customer* wants to change one or more pieces of information about a given *Address*, one must ensure that (a) the corresponding `Address` row that was “present” until the modification took place is INSERTed into the `AddressHistory` table, and also that (b) the `Address` row in question is UPDATEd with the new value(s). It'd be advantageous to carry out this process as a single unit of work inside a transaction.

Comment: @MDCCL, could you explain me the reason we need an `Address` entity? wouldn't be enough just have `CustomerAddress` ?

Comment: @Cristiano I just resplied to your question in the answer itself, in the new section entitled “Comment interactions”.

Answer (score 4):

*<sub>This answer was compiled from comments to the question.</sub>*

One solution would be to use a FK to the address table in the order table. That will let you see the addresses that were used for the order, and decouples the address from the User's current address.

In order to make this work you would have to insert a new address and link that new address to the User table. This means that addresses are write once and the edit is an illusion to the end user. You can effectively store the history of all addresses a user was associated with by moving the association from the User table to an association table with a time stamp. That would give you a history of edits/addresses, and maintain immutable data in the Address table.

[@MDCCL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/63644/mdccl) stated:

> [you should] organize your database structure having one table for retaining Order related data, and another table for keeping the Address info. And, yes, you can definitely have a table representing many-to-many relationship between these two entity types. If a User can change his Address(es) attributes, then you have to keep track of such modifications, thus you should enable the corresponding `AddressHistory`. [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107575/72091) is related to the latter aspect.

MDCCL also gave an overview on how to find the current address for a user here:

> In order to grab the latest version of a History table you have, you have to take into account the `MAX(AuditedDateTime)` of the corresponding `AddressId`. The first step is modeling/designing your best possible conceptual and logical arrangements, the second step is finding the proper ways to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and SELECT your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer this as a better explanation of/improvement over @Erik's answer.

Say your db includes these 3 tables :

- `user_table`
- `address_table`
- `orders_table`

In `address_table`, the Auto Increment field, `id` relates to both say, `user_table.adr_id` and `orders_table.addr_id`. 
 When a user creates his account and enters new address, it'll be stored in `address_table` as a new row and the row's `id`(say 10) will be referenced in `user_table.adr_id` as 10. 
 When the user orders something, the program loads the current address id from `user_table.adr_id` and it'll be stored in `orders_table.addr_id` as 10. 
 Now, sometime after, if the user decides the change his address, instead of `UPDATE address_table WHERE id==10...,`, you create a new row `INSERT into address_table.....`, the new data (`address_table.id` will be say 11) and update `user_table.adr_id=11`. 
 So the next time user orders something, `orders_table.addr_id` will get new address value. But past orders will still retain the old address data (as row 10 is not deleted and is still referenced from past orders in `orders_table`)
I don't know if it's advisable or not, but if you store the user's `id` in a field in `address_table`, you can even gather all the user's past addresses used.